# Compare contents of two files in Dreamweaver

Tags: compare, dreamweaver, text-files

Is it possible to compare the contents of two files in Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Yes**

However, dreamweaver doesn't have native compare tool. 
You will need to download a third-party merge or "diff" utility and configure Dreamweaver to integrate with this program.

[WinMerge utility](http://winmerge.org/downloads/)

To configure dreamweaver use compare tool go to:
Edit -> Preferences (**CTRL + U**) -> File Compare -> "Browse..." for executable file of compare tool

Comment: And then how to compare? I did not find anything related to "Compare Files" on the menu

Answer (score 8):

1. Download and install notepad++ (a wonderful free editor).
2. If you want to compare two local files:
   Open the two files in notepad++.
   Choose Plugins -> Compare (or alt-D).
3. If you want to compare a remote file with some other file, follow the instructions in Dreamweaver Help for comparing files.  Tell DW you will use notepad++.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Notepad++ is a quite amazing for a free editor!

Answer (score 6):

Don't think that DreamWeaver has that functionality, but it has been a little while. I use winmerge...it's free. Can be found [here](http://winmerge.org/).

Comment: Winmerge is a powerful tool, as well as wireshark.

Answer (score 2):

Dreamweaver 8 is able to do so (according to Adobe), however, you have to install a third-party-product to enable it (so I doubt that one can call this beeing able).

Here are some links:

http://mrmx.blogspot.com/2005/11/adding-file-compare-to-dreamweaver.html

http://wordpress.betech.virginia.edu/index.php/2007/08/20/compare-files-in-dreamweaver/

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/compare_utilities.html

http://www.communitymx.com/abstract.cfm?cid=B6FEB

My choice when it comes to comparing two files is WinMerge:

http://www.communitymx.com/abstract.cfm?cid=B6FEB